# Nautilus не открывает файл

Tags: linux, файлы, xubuntu

У меня xubuntu 18.04.2. В ней по дефолту стоит файловый менеджер thunar. Мне такой менеджер не оч, мне больше по душе nautilus. Устанавливаю наутилус , удаляю thunar, делаю наутилус дефолтным, захожу в наутилус, пытаюсь открыть какой-нибудь файл, например .png, но вместо ожидаемого открытия картинки в ristretto получаю попытку открыть файл(кружок загрузки) и в итоге ничего не открывается. Если кликнуть по файлу и нажать "открыть в другом приложении", и выбрать нужную программу, то все без проблем открывается.
Скачиваю обратно thunar, делаю его дефолтным, но наутилус не удаляю. Запускаю наутилус(при том что thunar дефолтный) и все файлы без проблем открываются. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы мне не пришлось thunar держать? Я примерно понимаю, что где-то прописан проводником для файлов именно thunar и когда я удаляю thunar и делаю наутилус дефолтным, то в этом "где-то" не меняется проводник по умолчанию. Как сделать чтобы поменялся? Какой файл редактировать? 
Пробовал [это](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968857/xubuntu-17-10-nautilus-doesnt-open-files), но нет такой директории и файла. Кстати по ссылки человек отписался что у него тоже нет такой директории и файла.
Еще нашел вариант редактировать /usr/bin/xdg-mime, но пока что не нашел нужных строк.

Comment: `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` это устаревший путь. Сейчас используется `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf Возможно так, но файлы все-равно не открываются

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf хорошо что я знаю английский. иначе искал бы век решение. вот [здесь](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1778069) все написано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для тех кому неохота читать комменты по данному багу, решение на багтрекере такое: 
Открыть терминал и прописать:
`sudo -s`
вводим свой пароль(не будет отображаться)
`mousepad /usr/share/xubuntu/applications/defaults.list`
В открывшемся файле ищем и удаляем строчку
`x-scheme-handler/file=exo-file-manager.desktop`
Далее сохраняем файл (ctrl+s). Возвращаемся в терминал и пишем
`mousepad ~/.config/mimeapps.list`
В этом файле ищем такую же строчку
`x-scheme-handler/file=exo-file-manager.desktop`
и удаляем оную.
сохраняем файл (ctrl+s)

У меня не было, но у кого-то может быть еще один файл в котором нужно удалить эту строку. Проверяем:
`mousepad ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`
Если открывшийся файл пустой, то ничего делать не нужно. И сохранять его тоже не нужно. Если не пустой то ищем и удаляем строку
`x-scheme-handler/file=exo-file-manager.desktop`
После всех этих действий у меня все заработало.
Описание данного бага [здесь](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/exo/+bug/1778069)